# Is is possible to use Xcode's touchbar without Xcode?

Tags: keyboard, xcode, virtualization, touch-bar

Xcode (or at least Xcode 9.2) has a `virtual touchbar` that you can launch by pressing `Command`+`Shift`+`5`. This virtual touchbar works on all applications that support it, and is always on top (of every window). I was wondering if I could somehow run the virtual touchbar without having Xcode open, as it uses a bunch of CPU power, and to see if it can be done out of interest.

The virtual touchbar, when running, is named `IDETouchBarSimulatorService` (in Activity Monitor) and seems to be located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/IDETouchBarSimulatorService.xpc/Contents/MacOS/IDETouchBarSimulatorService`.

Interestingly enough, when it's running, `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode` is listed (in Activity Monitor) as an open file.